# What is difference between ReadOnlyCollection<T> and ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder<T> in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, readonly-collection

Today I came across a dilemma what is the difference between `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder<T>` in .Net?

In `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` object we cannot add and remove items.

Where as in `ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder<T>` object we can add and remove items.

If we can add and remove items in `ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder<T>` object, then why the name readonly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630335.aspx), `ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder` is just a builder for read-only collections. The idea is that the builder is mutable, but would only be used in a small scope. You'd create a builder, add a load of elements, then call [`ToReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630319.aspx) to efficiently create a read-only view on the data. (This resets the builder, so you avoid the possibility of mutating the read-only collection after creation.)